# Discord python how can I get all the banned users?

Tags: discord.py

I was looking at the API Reference and I found fetch_ban(user). How can I check if the user is banned from the server, I was reading that it returns the the BanEntry, and get a boolean? Can I use member as well or I need to get the user? 
Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: Always link what you're talking about.

[fetch_ban](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_ban)
[BanEntry](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/guild.py) (discord.py source code)

If you go through the source code you will very quickly find this in the first lines:
`BanEntry = namedtuple('BanEntry', 'reason user')`

Returned is a BanEntry object **if the user is banned**, otherwise it returns a NotFound Exception.
So to check if a user is banned just do:

```py
async def is_banned(guild, user):
    try:
        entry = await guild.fetch_ban(user)
    except discord.NotFound:
        return False
    return True
```

This will also work with members, as they are basically user objects with a bit of extra.

BanEntry is a named tuple (if you need a refresher on those [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)).

Comment: But even if I banned a user on my server it doesn't show on the banned users

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna command that sending list of banned users

````
async def banlist(self, ctx):
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()
    loop = [f"{u[1]} ({u[1].id})" for u in bans]
    _list = "\r\n".join([f"[{str(num).zfill(2)}] {data}" for num, data in enumerate(loop, start=1)])
    await ctx.send(f"```ini\n{_list}```")
````

it gives list like this

```
[01] 尸仁长仈乃冂仨#0529 (269800030300033098)
[02] Yako#1001 (294113773333557952)
[03] Ping#9216 (46804048093530418)
[04] Vasky#6978 (494069478291921344)
```